# Option in dropdown box render outside

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

English is not my first language so i'm trying to be as specific as possible.
I have a table stored , all of the signed up account to my website. Inside of it i have a dropdown box automatically generated by php. So the problem is, when i click to changed the option in the dropdown menu, all of my option appeared outside of the box and was duplicated . Just like this [error dropdown box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6AJZ.png). Here is the code

```
$sql1="Select ID, user_login,user_email, display_name from wp_users ";
    $result1=mysqli_query($conn,$sql1);
    echo '<div id="div_package" style="display: none" >';
    echo '<div style="text-align:center"><h1>Đổi gói thành viên</h1><input type="text" id="myInput_pack" onkeyup="FilterUsers()" placeholder="Nhập thông tin người dùng cần tìm" title="Type in a user" style="width: 20%;height:35px; font-size: 16px;border: 1px solid black; margin-bottom: 12px;text-align:center"></div>';
    echo "<table id='tb_user' class='tbadmin' border='1' cellpadding='10' align='center' style='border-collapse:collapse'>";
    echo "<tr><th>ID người dùng</th><th>Tên đăng nhập</th><th>Tên hiển thị</th><th>Email</th><th>Gói hiện tại</th><th></th></tr>";
    while($row= mysqli_fetch_array($result1))
    {
        $userid=$row['ID'];
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.$userid.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['user_login'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['display_name'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['user_email'].'</td>';
        echo "<td><select name='package_$userid' id='package'>";
        $sqlcheck="SELECT 1 FROM wp_usermeta WHERE user_id=".$userid." AND meta_key='package_id' LIMIT 1";
        $result_check= mysqli_query($conn,$sqlcheck);
        if( mysqli_num_rows($result_check)!=0)
        {
            $sql_metaval="Select meta_value from wp_usermeta where user_id=".$userid." and meta_key='package_id'";
            $result_metaval= mysqli_query($conn,$sql_metaval);
            while($metaval= mysqli_fetch_array($result_metaval))
            {
                $val_package=$metaval['meta_value'];
                $test="Select post_title, ID from wp_posts where post_type='membership_package' and ID=".$val_package ;
                $sql2="Select post_title, ID from wp_posts where post_type='membership_package' and ID<>".$val_package ;
                $result_test=mysqli_query($conn,$test);
                if(mysqli_num_rows($result_test)==0)
                {
                    echo '<option value="">FREE</option>';
                    $sql3="Select post_title, ID from wp_posts where post_type='membership_package' and ID<>''";
                    $packages= mysqli_query($conn,$sql3);
                    while($pack = mysqli_fetch_assoc($packages)){
                        echo '<option value="'.$pack['ID'].'">'.$pack['post_title'].'</option>';
                    }
                    echo '</select>';
                }
                else 
                {
                    while($row= mysqli_fetch_array($result_test))
                    {
                        echo '<option value="'.$val_package.'">'.$row['post_title'].'</option>';
                    }
                    $packages= mysqli_query($conn,$sql2);
                    while($pack = mysqli_fetch_assoc($packages)){
                        echo '<option value="'.$pack['ID'].'">'.$pack['post_title'].'</option>';
                    }
                    echo '<option value="">FREE</option>';
                    echo '</select>';
                }
            }
        }
        
        else
        {
            echo '<option value="">FREE</option>';
            $sql3="Select post_title, ID from wp_posts where post_type='membership_package' and ID<>''";
            $packages= mysqli_query($conn,$sql3);
            while($pack = mysqli_fetch_assoc($packages)){
                echo '<option value="'.$pack['ID'].'">'.$pack['post_title'].'</option>';
            }
            echo '</select>';
        }
        echo "<td><a onclick='return confirmEdit();' href='#' id='update_$userid' class='update_user'>Cập nhật</a></td>";
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    
    echo "</table></br></div>";
```

It's appear that some kind of loop has happened in the first else section. I tried to delete the select tag in side that section, all the option appeared inside but  still be duplicated like [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmSFD.png)

Can someone show me how to solve the duplicate option? This has trouble me for days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem because you loop the selected option and not selected options in same `select` without exclude the select option from query of get not selected options (`$sql2`).

```
 $test="Select post_title, ID from wp_posts where post_type='membership_package' and ID=".$val_package ;
 $sql2="Select post_title, ID from wp_posts where post_type='membership_package' and ID<>".$val_package ;
 -------------------------------------------------------


   while($row= mysqli_fetch_array($result_test))
            {
                echo '<option value="'.$val_package.'">'.$row['post_title'].'</option>';
            }
            $packages= mysqli_query($conn,$sql2);
   while($pack = mysqli_fetch_assoc($packages)){
                echo '<option value="'.$pack['ID'].'">'.$pack['post_title'].'</option>';
            }
```